# Inherit from Seq

Tags: f#

I want to create my own custom collection type.

I define my collection as:

```
type A(collection : seq<string>) =
   member this.Collection with get() = collection

   interface seq<string> with
      member this.GetEnumerator() = this.Collection.GetEnumerator()
```

But this doesn't compile `No implementation was given for 'Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`

How do i do this?

Comment: You need `IEnumerable` as well as `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In F# `seq` is really just an alias for `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`.  The generic `IEnumerable<T>` also implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` and hence your F# type must do so as well.

The easiest way is to just have the non-generic one call into the generic one

```
type A(collection : seq<string>) =
  member this.Collection with get() = collection

  interface System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> with
    member this.GetEnumerator() =
      this.Collection.GetEnumerator()

  interface System.Collections.IEnumerable with
    member this.GetEnumerator() =
      upcast this.Collection.GetEnumerator()
```

Comment: You could save a few chars with `this.Collection.GetEnumerator() |> upcast`

Comment: @JoelMueller I'd actually never seen the upcast operator before. Much nicer.  Thanks!

Comment: @JoelMueller: Even shorter: `x.Collection.GetEnumerator() :> _`

Comment: @Daniel that's downright disturbing :).  Can you point me to the section of the spec which makes that work?  I'm very curious to read up on it.

Comment: @JaredPar : No spec link handy, but the return type of `GetEnumerator` is known because it's an interface implementation, so the upcast destination type can be inferred.

Comment: @ildjarn i'd always thought of `_` as an ignore feature (ignore a lambda param), i didn't realize it could be used as an inference tool in this way.  Nice

Comment: It can be used for types as well, so think of it more as an 'anonymous' rather than 'ignore' feature and you'll be much closer. E.g. in `let d = Dictionary<_,_>() in d.Add ("one", 1)`, `d` will be deduced as `Dictionary<string, int>`.

Comment: This is referred to in the [spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597408) as an _anonymous variable type_.

Comment: sample should be either 'this.Collection.GetEnumerator() :> _' or 'upcast this.Collection.GetEnumerator()'

Comment: The current answer doesn't use upcast properly, it needs to come first or upcast needs to be replaced with _ before i can accept the answer

Comment: It apparently needs both the generic and non generic interfaces. I think people have hinted to this but it should be more clear.